# Downloading and patching the kernel source

Tags: kernel, compiling, patch

I'd like to compile and install kernel 4.20.17 in Ubuntu 18.04. So I created a directory called /home/build/kernel and executed the following command:

```
git clone --depth 1 --single-branch --branch v4.20 git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel-test/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/mainline-crack v4.20.17
```

This created /home/build/kernel/v4.20.17:

```
arch   COPYING  debian         drivers   include  Kbuild   lib          Makefile  README   security  usr
block  CREDITS  debian.master  firmware  init     Kconfig  LICENSES     mm        samples  sound     virt
certs  crypto   Documentation  fs        ipc      kernel   MAINTAINERS  net       scripts  tools
```

Then I created v4.20.17-patch and downloaded the patches:

```
0001-base-packaging.patch                                        0004-debian-changelog.patch
0002-UBUNTU-SAUCE-add-vmlinux.strip-to-BOOT_TARGETS1-on-p.patch  0005-configs-based-on-Ubuntu-4.20.0-2.3.patch
0003-UBUNTU-SAUCE-tools-hv-lsvmbus-add-manual-page.patch
```

To apply the patch(s) I did the following:

```
/home/build/kernel/v4.20.17
patch -p1 < ../v4.20.17-patch/0001-base-packaging.patch

patching file debian.master/abi/5.0.0-7.8/abiname
patching file debian.master/abi/5.0.0-7.8/amd64/generic
patching file debian.master/abi/5.0.0-7.8/amd64/generic.compiler
etc....
```

However, this created new directories named debian.master and debian:

```
arch   COPYING  debian         drivers   include  Kbuild   lib          Makefile  README   security  usr
block  CREDITS  debian.master  firmware  init     Kconfig  LICENSES     mm        samples  sound     virt
certs  crypto   Documentation  fs        ipc      kernel   MAINTAINERS  net       scripts  tools
```

Is this the way it's supposed to be?

Unfortunately, [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.20.17/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.20.17/) doesn't have any instructions. But I wonder, what good do the new debian and debian.master directories do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to follow the wiki docs?  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel   (*Ubuntu uses debian packaging*)   Why such an old & *unsupported* kernel?  are you exploring *infections* & *security flaws*?

Comment: I've seen that but don't find it helpful. Well, if you must know... I need to compile and install a special kernel module which won't compile under anything higher than kernel version 4.x. So I'm guessing that 4.20.17 might be my best option. No one except myself is going to use or access the machine, so no need to worry about anything infectious or compromising security.

Comment: I was expecting to run make menuconfig, etc, but the mentioned URL does actually mention a debian directory. So perhaps everything's OK and the patch is supposed to be adding new directories and files, Debian/Ubuntu build specific. As I applied the remaining patches, it also patched files in other directories.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out everything is OK. I just had to continue with the remaining 4 patches to realize it's not only creating a debian and debian.master directory, but also patching some of the existing files. The info outlined in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel doesn't cover the procedure, but explains how to rebuild the Ubuntu kernel distribution package (.deb), the same you can actually download and install according to https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.20.17, for example. Btw, running debian/rules opens the usual configuration menu (make menuinstall), so you can also make some changes.

You can also download and install the .deb files from kernel.ubuntu.com... then copy /boot/config-4.20.17-042017-generic to .config in the kernel source directory, followed by the usual "make menuconfig, make modules_install, make install." You can also create a .deb package, e.g. make deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-mykernel. But if you want to build the "Ubuntu" flavored kernel, you use the Kernel build procedure mentioned in above Wiki document.